# libmysqlclient.a(client.c.o) is incompatible with elf_i386_fbsd

Tags: c++, c++14, shared-libraries, freebsd

I am trying to compile with gcc++9.3 and FreeBsd 12.1 my program and is giving me this  error in the end of the process

```
root@royal-server:/usr/src/sursa/Server/source/game/src # gmake -j20
linking ../game
/usr/bin/ld: error: /usr/local/lib/mysql/libmysqlclient.a(client.c.o) is incompatible with elf_i386_fbsd
/usr/bin/ld: error: /usr/local/lib/mysql/libmysqlclient.a(libmysql.c.o) is incompatible with elf_i386_fbsd
/usr/bin/ld: error: /usr/local/lib/mysql/libmysqlclient.a(adler32.o) is incompatible with elf_i386_fbsd
/usr/bin/ld: error: /usr/local/lib/mysql/libmysqlclient.a(crc32.o) is incompatible with elf_i386_fbsd
/usr/bin/ld: error: /usr/local/lib/mysql/libmysqlclient.a(deflate.o) is incompatible with elf_i386_fbsd
/usr/bin/ld: error: /usr/local/lib/mysql/libmysqlclient.a(inflate.o) is incompatible with elf_i386_fbsd
/usr/bin/ld: error: /usr/local/lib/mysql/libmysqlclient.a(trees.o) is incompatible with elf_i386_fbsd
/usr/bin/ld: error: /usr/local/lib/mysql/libmysqlclient.a(zutil.o) is incompatible with elf_i386_fbsd
/usr/bin/ld: error: /usr/local/lib/mysql/libmysqlclient.a(inffast.o) is incompatible with elf_i386_fbsd
/usr/bin/ld: error: /usr/local/lib/mysql/libmysqlclient.a(inftrees.o) is incompatible with elf_i386_fbsd
c++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
gmake: *** [Makefile:228: ../game] Error 1
root@royal-server:/usr/src/sursa/Server/source/game/src #
```

This is the patch on Makefile file .

```
# mysql
INCDIR += -I/usr/src/sursa/Server/extern/mysql/mysql
LIBDIR += -L/usr/local/lib/mysql
LIBS   += -lmysqlclient -lz -pthread -lm -lssl -lcrypto
### END
```

Comment: Looks like you didn't specify the correct build target platform. Therefore the ELF format doesn't match when you try to link. I don't have a solution, but maybe there are options in the makefile that you can change to the correct target platform.

Comment: Your computer ie an i386?